# ListView - How to respond to double click on non-item?

Tags: c#

What I want the ability to do is to double click on an empty row in a ListView and have it insert an item there. It already responds to the MouseDoubleClick event (for editing items) and that is working fine, but it appears that the MouseDoubleClick doesn't get fired if the double click is on a part of the ListView that doesn't contain a ListViewItem.

I've already tried responding to regular MouseDoubleClick events on the dialog itself, but the event doesn't get fired if it's on one of the "null areas" of the ListView.

Is there a way to do respond to a click on the "null areas" of a ListView without subclassing? What event/events needs/need to be handled in order to do this?

The current response to dialog double clicks (mouse and regular) looks like this:

```
if ( RectangleToScreen(list.ClientRectangle).Contains(e.X, e.Y) )
   list_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e);
```

and the list_MouseDoubleClick() (where m_SelItem is the currently selected item)

```
private void list_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if ( m_SelItem == null && m_Combo.Items.Count > 0 )
   {
    m_SelItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "", "Rd" });
    list.Items.Add(m_SelItem);
   }
...
}
```

EDIT: It seems that that whole region is just a black hole for events. For instance, I tried to respond to just a regular click/mouseclick event for both the ListView and the Dialog. Even those don't get triggered unless the click is on a ListViewItem. I'm guessing the only solution is going to be to subclass.

EDIT: Persistence pays off! It turns out that I can get the desired result by responding to the "MouseDown" event as such:

```
private void list_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Clicks == 2 )
        list_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: can you show your current code for the double click..? perhaps you could add some additional condition that checks if the SelectedIndex or Item value is null or empty then do your Insert..

Comment: I initially did what you suggested, the problem is that the double click event doesn't even get fired if it's not on a ListViewItem

Comment: @Sean, did you try handling the `DoubleClick` event instead? That one should be triggered even if the mouse cursor does not lie on an item.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, for both the ListView and the Dialog

Comment: Can you show the code you should still be able to do this you may be doing something incorrectly it should be on the `Double_Click` event instead and then you could check something like this `YourListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = string.Empty {then add new Item to Listview }` or `if(yourListView.SelectedItem != null){}` need to see the existing code

Comment: @DJKRAZE, it's fairly straightforward: EDIT: code in the OP

Comment: can you post that in the initial question also show the Full Method please, I can't make heads or tails out of what you have if you don't show full code block also if you are trying to trigger an event for a Double_Click it really should be in the Double_Click Event Handler

Comment: those two lines are literally the entire thing, the issue seems to be that those events don't get fired when the click is in the "null area"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MouseDown event ended up being what I needed:

```
private void list_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Clicks == 2 )
        list_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: I plan to, but it wants me to wait 2 days